# How do you create a peer to peer connection without port forwarding or a centeralized server?

Tags: p2p

I recall reading an article about a proposed way to do this. If I recall correctly, the researchers successfully created a connection to a client on another network without port forwarding by sending HTTP packets to each other (Alice pretends that Bob is an HTTP web server while Bob pretends Alice is a web server).

I'm not sure if that makes sense, but does anyone know where I can find the article or does anyone have any other ideas how to connect two clients together without a central server or port forwarding?

Is it even possible?

Edit: I would know the IPs of both computers and port the program listens on.

Comment: P2P can be archieved with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching, but without a centralized server, you cannot find the IPs of the other members.

Comment: @Deepsy even if you know the IP and port of both sides?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It is possible. I see at least **2 parts** to your question. (It is not going to be HTTP packet. It is a lot more complex than that.)

**First off**, I believe you might be talking about a concept called decentralized P2P network. The main idea behind a decentralized peer-to-peer network is the fact that nodes conjoint in such a network will not require central server or group of servers.

As you might already know, most common centralized peer-to-peer networks require such centralized system to exchange and maintain interconnectivity among nodes. The basic concept is such, a new node will connect to one of the main servers to retrieve information about other nodes on the network to maintain its connectivity and availability. The central system gets maintained through servers constantly synchronizing network state, relevant information, and central coordination among each other.

Decentralized network, on the other hand, does not have any structure or predetermined core. This peer-to-peer model is also called unstructured P2P networks. Any new node will copy or inherit original links from the "parent" node and will form its own list over time. There are several categories of decentralization of such unstructured networks.

Interestingly enough,  the absence of central command and control system makes it solution of choice for modern malware botnets. A great example could be Storm botnet,  which employed so-called Passive P2P Monitor (PPM). PPM was able to locate the infected hosts and build peer list regardless whether or not infected hosts are behind a firewall or NAT. Wikipedia's article **[Storm botnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_botnet)** is an interesting read. There is also great collaborative study called **[Towards Complete Node Enumeration in a Peer-to-Peer Botnet](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~hopper/p2pbot_asiaccs09.pdf)**, which provides excellent conceptual analysis and techniques employed by Storm botnet network.

**Second of all**, you might be talking about UDP hole punching. This is a technique or algorithm used to maintain connectivity between 2 hosts behind NATed router/gateway using 3rd comment host by means of a third rendezvous server.

There is a great paper by Bryan Ford, Pyda Srisuresh, and Dan Kegel called **[Peer-to-Peer Communication Across Network Address Translators](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/)**.

Comment: Thank you for the well written and sourced information. Looking more into UDP hole punching, I realized this is what I was looking for (for some reason I originally thought that required a centralized server, but now realize if I already have the IP and port info I can skip that part).

Answer (score 19):

As answered, a peer-to-peer connection requires establishment of a connection between two (presumably) residential computers, which will necessitate punching holes through both of their firewalls. For a concrete example of hole punching, see [pwnat: "The only tool to punch holes through firewalls/NATs without a third party"](https://github.com/samyk/pwnat). The process, put simply, goes like this:

1. The "server" (who doesn't know the client's IP address, but the client knows the server's) pings a very specific `ICMP Echo Request` packet to `1.2.3.4` every 30 seconds. The NAT, during translation, takes note of this packet in case it gets a response.
2. The client sends an `ICMP Time Exceeded` packet to the server, which is a type of packet that usually contains the packet that failed to deliver. The client, knowing in advance the exact packet that the server has been sending to `1.2.3.4`, embeds that whole packet in the Data field.
3. The NAT recognizes the Echo Request packet and happily relays the *whole* Time Exceeded packet, **source IP and all,** to the correct user, i.e. the server. Voila, now the server knows the client's IP and port number.
4. Now that the server knows the address, it begins to continually send UDP packets to the client, despite the fact that the client's NAT did not expect them and will therefore ignore them all.
5. The client begins sending UDP packets to the server, which will be recognized by the server's NAT as a response to the server's packets and route them appropriately.
6. Now that the client is sending UDP packets to the server, the server's stream of UDP packets starts getting properly routed by the client's NAT.

And, in 6 easy steps, you have established a UDP connection between a client and a server penetrating *two* residential firewalls. Take that, ISP!